# show that if $\lim_{z \rightarrow\infty} [-zf(z)]$ exists, it equals the residue of $f$ at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am using the Basic Complex Analysis book by Jerrold Marsden.
I know I should use the definition in 4.2.2 and the proposition 4.2.3 to solve this but i keep hitting a wall I don't know what  trick to manipulate them to show that it is true.

> conclusion of Def 4.2.2 
>   $$\operatorname{Res}(f;\infty)= - \operatorname{Res}((1/z^2)F(z);0)$$ where $F(z)=f(1/z)$

Comment: What is proposition 4.2.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit exists, then we have $$\lim_{z\to \infty}[-zf(z)] = \lim_{z \to 0}\left[-\frac1zF(z)\right]$$
Now note that for *any* (meromorphic) function $g$, if $\lim_{z\to 0}g(z)$ exists, then it is equal to $\operatorname{Res}(g(z)/z; 0)$. Combine these two facts, and you get
$$
\lim_{z\to \infty}[-zf(z)] = \operatorname{Res}\left(-\frac1{z^2}F(z); 0\right)
$$

Comment: what about the $-$ sign in the residue can it be taken out and how to prove it can. because if it is then $Res(- 1/z^2 F(z);0) = - Res(1/z^2 F(z);0) = Res(f,\infty)$

Comment: @FeerasAlDheiman By the definition of residue, if $g$ has residue $R$ at $0$, that means that $g(z) - R/z$ has an analytic antiderivative in a punctured disc around $0$. From this definition it is clear that $-g$ must have residue $-R$, since $(-g(z)) - (-R)/z = -(g(z) - R/z)$ has an analytic antiderivative. This goes for any complex constant $c \in \Bbb C$, not just $-1$ (so $c\cdot g$ has residue $cR$). It even works for any analytic function $h(z)$ for which $h(0)$ is finite ($gh$ has residue $h(0)R$).

Comment: @FeerasAlDheiman Scratch that last sentence about $h$. On second thoughts, I don't think that's right.

Comment: thanks, I just needed to make sure that what I have is correct for the last part, since my instructor is strict in this class. even intuitive stuff must be written down for a full credit in anything. that's is why i don't want to make a simple mistake that will cause me to lose points in the future.

Comment: @FeerasAlDheiman Well, if you're too fast, you see what can happen just in my comment above. The proof in my comment works for constants, and I thought the result held for functions, but I found a counterexample ($g = \frac{1}{z^2}, h = z$) too late to edit it out. To fix it, you would have to insist on something like $zg(z)$ having a removable singularity. It is not a bad idea for your instructor to insist on you being thurough.